# Fix scss path issues in react app while compiling

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, scss-mixins

```
my-react-app
|_public
|  |_assets
|    |_style.scss
|    |_elements
|      |_ _test.scss
|_src
   |_index.scss
   |_index.js
```

That is my folder structure for my react app
index.js

```
import './index.scss';
```

index.scss

```
@import "../public/assets/style";
```

style.scss

```
@import url(elements/_test.scss);
```

_test.scss

```
body {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
Error: Can't resolve 'elements/_test.scss' in 'C:\Users\j**\my-app\src'
```

How to import correctly so i dont get the above error

Answer (score 0):

It can not read scss, you need to link css file. you can do it with vs code plugins I use Live scss compiler it works fine(it will save all your styles in one file). or convert them here: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was, moving ( in your case) _test.scss into the src directory or whatever directory the file you imported _test.scss was